# How to check Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray If null Or get length

Tags: json, dynamic, .net-core

I have array coming in C# code of type dynamic. Before process it I need to check if 'answers' array has record so I tried number of attempt and I am not getting any result. I have tried if(array==null), Count(), Length, DefaultIfEmpty()

```
answerItem
{{
 "questionId": "9ca96ed8-ec33-c09b-a634-0e3e32245f99",
 "answers": [],
}}
```

above record is with null answers.

if record in answer array then it will be like

```
"answer":[
    {"id":"333", "value":"my answer"}
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (answerItems.value.HasValues) {
    foreach(var ansValue in answerItems.value) {
        var ansId = Convert.ToString(ansValue["id"]);
        var ans = Convert.ToString(ansValue["value"]);
     }
 }
```